# Missing classes in PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside2

I just upgraded the Python version (Ubuntu, miniconda3, pip) from 3.9 to 3.11 and found that the classes QRegularExpressionValidator and QDeadlineTimer are missing from PySide2 now. Have they been deprecated?

However, the PySide version stayed the same (PySide2==5.15.2.1).

I downgraded to Python 3.9 and it's there again in the PySide2 package.

Comment: Looking at the library on pypi there seems to only be wheels up to version 3.10, so maybe there are some compatibility issues with 3.11.

Comment: Interesting. pypi also states "required Python version: <3.11". I tried with Python 3.10 and the classes are there. If you make it an answer, I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from comment.

Looking at the library on PyPI there seems to only be wheels up to version 3.10, so maybe there are some compatibility issues with 3.11.

[PyPI PySide2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/)

`Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <3.11`